# ASP.NET Chart Control too slow or doesn't render

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-charts

I have a web page rendering two pie charts using the ASP.NET 3.5 chart controls. On my dev server (IIS 5.1) the charts load well. On the QA server, the charts load pretty slowly and sometimes one or both of them doesn't even load.
[image]

I am loading the charts using the  codebehind tag. Is there anything else that could be done to make these charts run faster?

**Note:** I was previously using dotNETCHARTING and never had any issues with it. Nothing else has changed except for the charting engine.

Comment: without identify what's slow (database access, memory consumption, cpu load), it's very hard to help

Comment: Also, try posting your code-behind there could be an issue there.

Comment: Load time is slow. The page renders completely but the charts take much longer. 
As I mentioned, nothing else has changed but the Chart control. Sometimes it complains about the Chart Handler and sometimes it doesn't. Which make absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on page tracing and stick some tracing code in your code behind such as:

```
Trace.Write("Opening DB connection");
Trace.Write("Gathering Data");
Trace.Write("Closing DB connection");
Trace.Write("Starting Graph");
Trace.Write("finished graph");
```

And then check how long each one takes to execute.  This will give you a clue as to what part is slowing the page down,  once you know that you can dig deeper into why it is happening.

See here for more : http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020910.htm

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an ancient thread but I had the same scenario and this worked for me: In your WebConfig `<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;timeout=30;privateImages=false" />`

The 'memory' setting will avoid file issues (I have virus detection on the server !)
The 'timeout' gives the page heaps of time to render the image